# How can I download Facebook Messenger (official) for my Windows Phone?

Tags: apps, facebook, messenger

When I tried to download Facebook Chat Messenger (the official one and not from a third party) from my Windows Phone (through the App store) I couldn't find any official app, only many unofficial FB chat messengers. I want the official one so I checked at https://www.facebook.com/mobile/messenger but I saw apps only for Android and iPhone and not for Windows. Is the Facebook Chat Messenger not available for Windows phones?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but have you seen the option in messaging settings to "Use Facebook Chat"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook Messenger for Windows Phone is available from 05 March 2014.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/facebook-messenger/3219d30d-4a23-4f58-a91c-c44b04e6a0c7

Answer (score 5):

Facebook messenger is not available yet for Windows Phone, but it's coming soon: http://www.wpcentral.com/facebook-messenger-announced-windows-phone